# Определение местоположения в переменную

Tags: javascript

Есть код для определения местоположения. Город выводится алертом.
Как записать город в переменную, чтобы можно было использовать в других скриптах на странице?
С js практически не знаком.

```js
$(function(){
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
ymaps.geolocation.get({autoReverseGeocode: true, provider:"browser"})
.then(function (res)  {
var g = res.geoObjects.get(0);
alert(g.getLocalities()[0]);
})
.catch(function (err) {
console.log('Не удалось установить местоположение', err);
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data;//объявляем глобальную переменную
function set(value) {
    data = value;
}
$(function () {
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        ymaps.geolocation.get({autoReverseGeocode: true, provider: "browser"}).then(function (res) {
            var g = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            setTimeout(set(g.getLocalities()[0]), 3000);//заносим значение
            alert(g.getLocalities()[0]);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Не удалось установить местоположение', err);
        });
    }
});
```

Таким образом в переменной `data` Будет храниться позиция и она будет в глобальной области видимости. Только учтите, вы должны объявить `data` В самой первой области видимости, вне функций и блоков кода.

Comment: не получается.  

`var data;//объявляем глобальную переменную
$(function(){
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        ymaps.geolocation.get({autoReverseGeocode: true, provider:"browser"}).then(function (res)  {
            var g = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            data = g.getLocalities()[0];//заносим значение
            alert(g.getLocalities()[0]);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Не удалось установить местоположение', err);
});
}
alert(data);`
выводит undefined

Comment: Добавьте полный код, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554291/176064

Comment: Интересно к прочтению, благодарю. :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов
http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6AT/65/

Comment: @kkott vp_arth дал ссылку на очень обширный ответ.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов спасибо, но я ничего оттуда не понял. с js не знаком.

Comment: Я обновил ответ. @kkott

Comment: @kkott только тестируйте у себя на машине потому что на jsfiddle не выполяется ничего в функции где мы хотели присвоение сделать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов спасибо, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, понял в чем дело. Город определяется через несколько секунд после загрузки сайта, а переменную проверяется сразу.

Comment: @kkott обновил ответ, тепер мы просто ждем 3 секунды а потом заносим данные в переменную.